# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider - while migrating AngularJS1 to Angular6

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

I'm trying to do upgrade components written in **AngularJS1** to **Angular6**. I'm taking the approach of having the wrappers for all the existing AngularJS1 component by extending "**UpgradeComponent**" placed under the folder "directive-wrappers" in my example.

while loading the application I get the console error as

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testDirective2DirectiveProvider <- testDirective2Directive
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/unpr?p0=testDirective2DirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20testDirective2Directive
    at eval (angular.js:138)
    at eval (angular.js:4924)
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5084)
    at eval (angular.js:4929)
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5084)
    at Function.UpgradeHelper.getDirective (upgrade_helper.ts:56)
    at new UpgradeHelper (upgrade_helper.ts:52)
    at TestDirective2Wrapper.UpgradeComponent (upgrade_component.ts:106)
    at new TestDirective2Wrapper (TestDirective2Wrapper.ts:27)
    at createClass (provider.ts:265) "<app-root _nghost-c0="">"
```

[image]

To mimic the same application online I have created the same angularjs directives and its wrappers in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-xvu8bw)

Comment: Could you show the code for that directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with the **`docsSampleDirective.js`** file.

You've initialized the AngularJS Module there for the second time when you already initialized the **`testApp`** module in the **`app.module.js`** file. Just get rid of the dependency array from there:

```
angular
  .module("testApp")
  .controller("Controller", [
    "$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.customer = {
        name: "Naomi",
        address: "1600 Amphitheatre"
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive("docsSimpleDirective", function() {
    return {
      template: "Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}"
    };
  });
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-nl1vun?file=AngularJsApp/docsSimpleDirective/docsSimpleDirective.js) for your ref.

Comment: When I try to add some controllers, I get the same error message. I tried adding studentController and homePageController, but not able to load it. Any ideas why I'm facing this issue?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-c8h6uv

Comment: Would it be possible to ask another question regarding that? Would make this thread more focused on a single problem.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369756/error-while-loading-controllers-migrating-angularjs1-to-angular6 - posted this question