# Error while loading controllers - migrating AngularJS1 to Angular6

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

I'm trying to do upgrade components written in AngularJS1 to Angular6. I'm taking the approach of having the wrappers for all the existing AngularJS1 component by extending "**UpgradeComponent**" placed under the folder "**directive-wrappers**" in my example. When I try to add some controllers which doesn't have any directives, I get the error message

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testDirective2DirectiveProvider <- testDirective2Directive
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/unpr?p0=testDirective2DirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20testDirective2Directive
    at eval (angular.js:138)
    at eval (angular.js:4924)
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5084)
    at eval (angular.js:4929)
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5084)
    at Function.UpgradeHelper.getDirective (upgrade_helper.ts:56)
    at new UpgradeHelper (upgrade_helper.ts:52)
    at TestDirective2Wrapper.UpgradeComponent (upgrade_component.ts:106)
    at new TestDirective2Wrapper (TestDirective2Wrapper.ts:27)
    at createClass (provider.ts:265) "<app-root _nghost-c69="">"
```

I tried adding studentController and homePageController, but not able to load it. Any ideas why I'm facing this issue?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-c8h6uv

Comment: How did you solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that need to be addressed. First, in the studentController.js file, you are using the `var mainApp = angular.module("testApp", []);` syntax which is resetting the AngularJS module and everything that got instantiated before is being removed.

To answer your question about the controllers, AngularJS controllers can't be upgraded directly using `UpgradeComponent` (see https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angularjs-component-directives-from-angular-code) because they aren't components/directives that have a template. That is why the error you get (after fixing the first issue) is `Unknown provider: studentControllerDirectiveProvider <- studentControllerDirective`. It can't find a directive for the reference studentController, so it is adding Directive to see if that has anything.

To fix this, either convert the controller in AngularJS to a directive with a template, or convert it to a service in AngularJS and then inject it into Angular using the `UpgradeModule`. Keep in mind you will need a template somewhere for this controller so it can be upgraded to Angular. Please see a working example of this in my stackblitz below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-zs6waw?file=app%2Fdirective-wrappers%2FstudentControllerWrapper.ts

Comment: thanks for you reply, can you please show me a example to convert controller to a directive?

Comment: my requirement is I don't want to touch my existing controllers, instead create a directive wrapper for the controller and do the upgrade.. let me know if it is possible with a example ?

Comment: Can you please answer my query- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468481/how-to-create-wrapper-directives-for-controller-in-angularjs